# Linkformat inside of Textmails

Tags: .net

First off , my english is not very good so be nice :)

---

My Problem :

Via .NET Code i send mails to several receivers. These Mails contain a link that is decrypted like this :

"http://www.abc.com/Defaul.aspx?id=o70pzUOz65E="

The Problem now is that, f.e. in Outlook the Link ends before the "=" and the "=" is simply written without being part of the link. The Mails are simple TextMails and are encoded with "MailEncoding.QuotedPrintable"

Does someone got a hint for me, how i can show the complete Link without using HTML Mails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a good solution without changing the URL.

You might be able to change the URL by adding an extra parameter on the end. When I tried this URL in a plain-text Outlook 2007 email, it highlighted the whole thing correctly:

http://www.abc.com/Defaul.aspx?id=o70pzUOz65E=&x=1

ASP.NET should ignore extra querystring arguments in a GET request. So it will ignore the "&x=1" and just process the "id".

Comment: Yeah i made it like that yesterday evening. Although it's just a workaround it works perfect